# Tkinter widgets not working when called from a different file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In my Tkinter project, there is one functionality which goes like this:

1. User clicks on a button
2. A new settings window opens
3. The settings window has it's own widgets and related functions

I used the `Toplevel` call from Tkinter to create a new window. The problem that occurs is that even though I am able to see the widgets on the new window, they aren't working. So far I have a button with an image on it. The image does not appear (I tested for the path and it is correct), and also nothing happens when I click it. I have tested this window as a seperate Tkinter project so I know it works. It does not work when called from a different file.

This is the main code:

```py
from tkinter import*
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import ttk
import os

import settingsController

root = Tk()
root.title("Main")
root.geometry("480x320") 
root.resizable(0, 0) 
root.configure(background="white")
root.overrideredirect(0)

settings_logo = PhotoImage(file="settings_icon.gif")
settings_button = Button(root, image=settings_logo,command=lambda: settingsController.begin(root))
settings_button.place(x= 277, y= 220)

settings_label = Label(root, fg = "black", font = "Times 10 bold", text="Settings", background= "white")
settings_label.place(x = 274, y = 275, width= 60, height= 25)

root.mainloop()
```

And this is the relevant part of the settingsController

```py
from tkinter import *
root = None
def begin(rootWindow):

    global root

    root = Toplevel(rootWindow)

    root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    # root.geometry("400x400")

    # root.title("Settings")
    root.configure(bg="white")

    screen_width = rootWindow.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = rootWindow.winfo_screenheight()

    img = PhotoImage(file="icon_50x50.png")

    btn = Button(root,image=img,bg="white",command=foo,height=50,width=50)
    btn.place(x=0,y=0)

    print("Screen width:", screen_width)
    print("Screen height:", screen_height)
```

How do I accomplish this? This is a big project and I've been specifically asked to create seperate files, so I cannot dump all of this in just 1 file.

Comment: I think you have to add a ```root.mainloop()``` in the ```settingsController```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: @Sujay: you should only call `mainloop` a single time for the life of the program.

Answer (score 0):

The script is initializing ktinker again. You need to import the second script from the first script and then run a function in the second script with 'root' as a parameter.

Notes:

> This is an example and you can add your code to it (I am using your
> script 2). This code considers that both of the scripts are in the same directory.

script1.py:

```
from tkinter import*
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

import script2
script2.begin(root, rootWindow)
```

script2.py:

```py
from tkinter import *
def begin(root, rootWindow):
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    # root.geometry("400x400")

    # root.title("Settings")
    root.configure(bg="white")

    screen_width = rootWindow.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = rootWindow.winfo_screenheight()

    img = PhotoImage(file="icon_50x50.png")

    btn = Button(root,image=img,bg="white",command=foo,height=50,width=50)
    btn.place(x=0,y=0)

    print("Screen width:", screen_width)
    print("Screen height:", screen_height)
```

So basically what I did here was pass the root that you initialized in the first script to the second script by calling a function in the second script from the first script.